# SonarQube is unable to analyze file : foo : index (0) must be less than size (0)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm running SonarQube 4.5.4 server and analyzing via maven 3.0.5 using Sonar plugin for Jenkins. I'm had no issues analyzing other projects, but one is giving me this error when doing Java AST scan (please note I removed the actual java source filename):

```
01:15:45.429 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project netbase: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : foo.java: index (0) must be less than size (0) -> [Help 1]
01:15:45.430 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project netbase: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/acc1/jenkins/workspace/backend-all-in-one-nightly/prospero-framework/src/main/java/com/accelovation/prospero/cluster/NodeImpl.java'
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
01:15:45.430    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
01:15:45.431    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
01:15:45.431    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
01:15:45.431    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
01:15:45.431    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
01:15:45.431    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
01:15:45.431    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
01:15:45.431    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
01:15:45.431    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:15:45.432    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
01:15:45.432 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/acc1/jenkins/workspace/backend-all-in-one-nightly/prospero-framework/src/main/java/com/accelovation/prospero/cluster/NodeImpl.java'
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
01:15:45.432    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
01:15:45.433    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
01:15:45.433    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
01:15:45.433    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
01:15:45.433    ... 19 more
01:15:45.433 Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/acc1/jenkins/workspace/backend-all-in-one-nightly/prospero-framework/src/main/java/com/accelovation/prospero/cluster/NodeImpl.java'
01:15:45.433    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:102)
01:15:45.433    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:75)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:131)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:124)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
01:15:45.434    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
01:15:45.435    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
01:15:45.436    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
01:15:45.436    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
01:15:45.436    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
01:15:45.436    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:15:45.437    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
01:15:45.437    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
01:15:45.437    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
01:15:45.437    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
01:15:45.438    ... 22 more
01:15:45.438 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index (0) must be less than size (0)
01:15:45.438    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:301)
01:15:45.438    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:280)
01:15:45.438    at com.google.common.collect.EmptyImmutableList.get(EmptyImmutableList.java:106)
01:15:45.438    at org.sonar.java.ast.parser.ListTreeImpl.get(ListTreeImpl.java:170)
01:15:45.438    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.getSuppressWarningArgs(JavaFilesCache.java:185)
01:15:45.438    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.handleSuppressWarning(JavaFilesCache.java:162)
01:15:45.438    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.handleSuppressWarning(JavaFilesCache.java:153)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.visitMethod(JavaFilesCache.java:137)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:215)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.visitClass(JavaFilesCache.java:110)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:199)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
01:15:45.439    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.visitClass(JavaFilesCache.java:110)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:199)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:136)
01:15:45.440    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
01:15:45.441    at org.sonar.java.JavaFilesCache.scanFile(JavaFilesCache.java:94)
01:15:45.441    at org.sonar.java.DefaultJavaResourceLocator.scanFile(DefaultJavaResourceLocator.java:126)
01:15:45.441    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
01:15:45.441    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
01:15:45.441    ... 59 more
01:15:45.441 [ERROR] 
01:15:45.442 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
01:15:45.442 [ERROR] 
01:15:45.442 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
01:15:45.442 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix?

Comment: What's the version of Java plugin ?

Comment: Version 3.4 (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin)

Comment: Would you be able to share the code source of the file ? Especially the lines where there is a @SuppressWarnings annotation.

Comment: Hi @benzonico, I do not won't to post the code to a public forum, but you pointed me in the right location. This is older code and I don't think the SupressWarnings annotations are still relevant especially after I have since removed FindBugs, PMD, and Checkstyle plugins from Sonar. I removed the SuppressWarnings annotations from this file and now Sonar completes successfully.

Comment: @ScottWolk great to hear that you solved the issue ! But as maintainer of sonar-java plugin, I would be really interested in a reproducer though as this really sound like a bug: would you be able to narrow down the issue to a small anonymous example and share it ?

Comment: @benzonico I am facing same problem but I don't have any `@SuppressWarnings` annotation in file. Are there any other annotations/phrases  too which may cause problem?

Comment: @AnkitSharma if you don't have any `@SuppressWarnings` annotations in your file, I would be glad to see the related stack trace.

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam Stack trace is too long, where should I put it so that you can access it easily?

Comment: You can remove any reference to your project and files and use online sharing tools such as http://pastebin.com/. You can also use our google group and create a new thread in it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam Sorry for late reply. I have posted my stack trace at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/iKaduKBFIag

Answer (score 1):

A ticket has been created on our side to handle the issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1233

For a similar problem, the issue was caused by using non-default `SuppressWarnings` annotations without parameters (for instance the annotation from findbugs, and not `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`) and not providing the binaries of these classes for the analysis.

Providing binaries for the analysis should solve the issue.